# delphi what is difference of [ and { in json array

Tags: json, delphi

I have a JSON string and need to parse it

```
JsonString :='{"uid":"1","full_name":"test","user_name":"test","mobile":"0999","send_sms":""'    +',"recieve_sms":"","mob_app":"","password":"test","email":"","credit":"0.00","status":"agent","add_date":"2020-01-04 13:05:32","agent":"0","theme":""}';
LJsonArr    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString) as TJSONArray;
   for LJsonValue in LJsonArr do
   begin
      for LItem in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do begin
      memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s : %s',[TJSONPair(LItem).JsonString.Value, TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value]));
      end;
   end;
```

this not working but if I put JSON string in a `[]` the code work well.

what is the difference of `[{}]` with `{}` or `[]` and how can I process my string with just `{}`

Comment: `[ .. ]` denotes an **array** - one or several items;  `{ .... }` denotes an **object**

Comment: You should read on how [the syntax of JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the JSON in question does not contain *any* arrays at all, so all of your typecasts to `TJSONArray` are wrong. The JSON represents a single object (a `TJSONObject`) containing name/value pairs of strings, nothing more.

By surrounding the JSON with `[]`, you create an array that contains 1 element, an object. So your outer loop is satisfied, but your inner loop is still wrong since it would need to typecast `LJsonValue` to `TJSONObject` rather than `TSONArray`.

To process the original JSON correctly, try this instead:

```pascal
JsonString :='{"uid":"1","full_name":"test","user_name":"test","mobile":"0999","send_sms":""' +',"recieve_sms":"","mob_app":"","password":"test","email":"","credit":"0.00","status":"agent","add_date":"2020-01-04 13:05:32","agent":"0","theme":""}';
LJsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString);
if LJsonValue <> nil then
try
  LJsonObj := LJsonValue as TJSONObject;
  for LJsonPair in LJsonObj do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s : %s',[LJsonPair.JsonString.Value, LJsonPair.JsonValue.Value]));
  end;
finally
  LJsonValue.Free;
end;
```